# Papery lumps in avocado fruit

Tags: avocado

I have a well established avocado tree of probably 30-40 years in San Jose, CA 95112. It is about 25 feet tall. I believe this is a Bacon or a Zutano variety (elongated pear shape with green thin skin).

This years crop looks exactly like previous years, however there are beige lumps (about the size of an apple seed) in the avocado meat that are kind of papery. This is similar to the strings that you sometimes get especially in very ripe avocados, but they are not attached to anything. This makes them quite unpleasant to eat.

Any idea what this might be?

Last year I fertilized the plant with citrus/avocado fertilizer like I have done before. Also I didn't water as much as I have in previous years.

Comment: I don't know for sure, and can't find any information that corresponds with the condition you're describing, but it sounds like a disorder of some kind caused by certain growing conditions. I'm thinking of Apple Water Core, which produces glassy bits in apples when they're environmental conditions haven't been entirely appropriate (excessive pruning, very high light intensity, very high temperatures, stripping or extensive damage to the tree's bark). This sounds like a similar kind of disorder but I can't find any info to confirm or deny this. Most disorders in avocado have other symptoms too.

Comment: @Bamboo I suspect that this is a watering issue. I'll try to upload some pictures. Could you refer me to some resources that you used to investigate this?

Comment: I just googled your description 'beige lumps in avocado fruits', but found nothing much of any help anywhere. I've had avocados I've bought to eat with those lumps in, just one or two occasionally. I'm guessing its a cultural thing, simply because other types of fruit can produce odd things when the conditions aren't quite right - as watering is the only thing you've changed, it may well be something to do with that. I drew a complete blank on lumps of any description in the body of the fruits on my research...most 'lumps' referred to were on the skins.

Comment: Ok… thanks anyways. I'll try to water more this summer (bummer that California is in a drought).

Comment: This question cannot be properly answered without a photograph, and possibly more detail.